# Errors while trying to build ReadWrite example in Code Composer Studio 4

Tags: read-write, code-composer

I'm trying to build the Read Write example in CCS4 and get many "undefined identifier" errors:

> identifier "MAX_PROCESSORS" is undefined
>
> identifier "MPCSOBJ_PROC_PADDING" is undefined
>
> identifier "MPCS_TURN_PADDING" is undefined

etc.

These are indeed undefined. However, the example is supposed to be complete and work without me changing anything. What could be the problem?